# Embed png image in html file using Jinja2

Tags: html, image, jinja2

I'm using Jinja2 to create html reports as a single html file. I would like to include the company logo inside the html file rather than link to it; in this way the logo is displayed  even if the person reading the report is offline. Can this be automatically done using Jinja2? If not how can I embed a png image in the html manually?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

look for a Base64 encoder on Google (e.g. http://www.opinionatedgeek.com/dotnet/tools/base64encode/). After that you can insert

```
<img src="data:image/png;base64,BASE64_ENCODED_DATA">
```

in place for the logo :)

Comment: Interesting... perhaps I spoke too soon.