# How can I literally embed a small image (icon) in Html ONCE and unpack it many times?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

This is in reference to this answer:  [Embed png image in html file using Jinja2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4819136/embed-png-image-in-html-file-using-jinja2/4819199#4819199)

Is it possible to embed the base64 encoding of my image once in the Html, but use it in many places?  I can use jQuery if needed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simply put your base64 image in an IMG tag, say with an id="logo", then wherever you want to use it just have an IMG tag with an empty "src" attribute and a class="logo". Then use jQuery to set the "src" attribute for those IMGs to the master. e.g.

jQuery:

```
var src = $('img#logo').attr('src');
$('img.logo').attr('src', src);
```

HTML:

```
    ......<img id="logo" src="data:image/png;base64,
iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAoAAAAKCAYAAACNMs+9AAAABGdBTUEAALGP
C/xhBQAAAAlwSFlzAAALEwAACxMBAJqcGAAAAAd0SU1FB9YGARc5KB0XV+IA
AAAddEVYdENvbW1lbnQAQ3JlYXRlZCB3aXRoIFRoZSBHSU1Q72QlbgAAAF1J
REFUGNO9zL0NglAAxPEfdLTs4BZM4DIO4C7OwQg2JoQ9LE1exdlYvBBeZ7jq
ch9//q1uH4TLzw4d6+ErXMMcXuHWxId3KOETnnXXV6MJpcq2MLaI97CER3N0
vr4MkhoXe0rZigAAAABJRU5ErkJggg==" alt="logo">
    ......
    ......<img class="logo" src="" alt="logo">
```

I'm glad you asked this question as it's something I wanted to do a couple of weeks ago in a lightbox clone (slimbox2). I wanted to embed the image in the javascript, rather than load it from a file, since the image is specific to the javascript (nice "next", "prev", "play", "pause" buttons) and I did not want the user to have to store them in a specific location.

BEWARE, this type of data is fine for IE8 and above but apparently not Internet Explorer 7 and below. See:

> http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_URI_scheme

Regards
        Neil

Answer (score 1):

Load it once and use the jQuery .clone method to copy the image element.

Or, alternatively, load it from a server like a proper grown up :)

Comment: "like a proper grown up :)"  That wasn't necessary.

Comment: Yeah sorry. Its just not really the use-case for these things. Anyway, proper grown ups stick their images on Amazon cloud clusters...

Comment: OP should've mentioned in here too, but in the linked question he mentions that it's for a report file that needs to be viewable offline so loading from a server isn't applicable.

Comment: Offline viewing is a "pro", but a "con" is that it won't work in IE7 and below.

Answer (score 1):

An alternative is to embed the image in CSS and use the CSS class wherever you need the image.

Comment: You'd have to use it as a background image on a DIV (or similar) though - not as a true IMG in the HTML - wouldnt you?

Comment: @Spacedman - You will be able to use it anywhere you could use an image in CSS. This includes `UL` bullet points, background images and more.

Comment: Yes, but an image in CSS doesn't have the semantics of an IMG tag in HTML. The semantic requirement here isn't clear. Although if the OP wants an IMG tag perhaps the IMG could be transparent and have its background-image set by css - can an IMG have a CSS background-image? That's sick :)

Comment: @Spacedman - Interesting thought... I don't think that's possible though. It may be a good option for the OP though, depending on requirements.